# What's the difference between a generic trait and a trait with associative types?

Tags: rust

for example

```
trait Processor {
    type Input;
    type Output;

    fn process(&self, input: Self::Input) -> Self::Output;
}
```

and

```
trait Processor<Input, Output> {
    fn process(&self, input: Input) -> Output;
}
```

seem pretty close to me.
One thing i found from the book is that you cannot implement multiple trait instances and cause ambiguity with associative type but you can with generics. like this:

```
impl Processor<String, i32> for Foo {...}
impl Processor<String, String> for Foo {...}
foo.process("hi"); // ambiguity: which one to call?
```

However in most situations the implementing structures are themselves generic and are thus de-ambiguous automatically:

```
struct Foo<T,U> {...}
impl<T,U> Processor<T,U> for Foo<T,U> {...}
// 1 to 1 impl for each instance of <T,U>
```

So aside from this why the associative type approach is more expressive than generics? Is there some situation where only associative type makes sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the main reason to use generics in trait definition is that you can make many different implementation of the same trait for each type.

Great example here is [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) trait. Take a look at [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-AsRef%3C%5Bu8%5D%3E-for-String): thanks to `AsRef` implementations it can be borrowed as `Path`, plain bytes `[u8]`, native `str` or even `OsStr`.

To understand difference between these two approaches I'd suggest you to mix both in your example.

Consider some `Processor` which accepts different `Input`s and produces concrete `Output` for each `Input`:

```rust
trait Processor<Input> {
    type Output;

    fn process(&self, input: Input) -> Self::Output;
}
```

Now you can create many different implementations to process each type of `Input` you want. But each `Input` type will produce the only one `Output` type.

Another great example here is family of `std::ops` traits, like [`std::ops::Add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Add.html). It takes a single generic as input and defines `Output` type. You can overload `+` operation on any type you've created and mix them together, so adding different types through `+` operation may produce different result types.

Comment: Another good counter-example from the standard library is the related traits `Iterator` and `IntoIterator`. These traits are _not_ generic, because otherwise `for` loops wouldn't know which implementation to use. Plus it would be a gigantic pain to use iterator utility methods like `.map` without annotating types all over the place.

Comment: I see now from the Add trait: A type T should be addable to many other types S, but a given T + S operation should always have a single output type!

Answer (score 2):

> However in most situations the implementing structures are themselves generic and are thus de-ambiguous automatically:
>
> ```rust
> struct Foo<T,U> {...}
> impl<T,U> Processor<T,U> for Foo<T,U> {...}
> // 1 to 1 impl for each instance of <T,U>
> ```

This is because you *specifically* chose it to use the same types as the `Processor` struct and its `impl`. You can definitely do this:

```rust
struct Foo<T,U> {...}
impl<T,U,X,Y> Processor<X,Y> for Foo<T,U> {...}
// Different type than the struct!
```

...and it will compile alright. But this lead to the problem that you mentioned; the struct `Foo` now may implement the trait `Processor` multiple times with different `Input`/`Output` type.

Besides, now whenever you call any function associated by the trait `Process` from that struct `Foo`, you have to specify the return value:

```rust
let foo = Foo::new();
let output = foo.process(56);
// Rust will complain that you need to have an explicit type!
```

TL;DR: Yes, associated type is more specific for this kind of work. There are of course times when generic traits are needed, like in `std::ops::*`.